# Layer-backed view cuts a hole in NSWindow shadow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, calayer, nswindow

I turned on layer-backing for a view which lies on the edge of the window and now this window doesn't draw shadow in that area. Is there anything I can do to prevent window from losing its shadow?

**Edit:**
Window has `setOpaque:NO`, if I set it to `YES` then everything is ok, but I need it to be `NO`.

Is there a reliable way to draw a custom shadow around window? Then I can disable default shadow and draw it myself.

[image]

Comment: does the window's content view have a layer? if not what happens if you turn it on?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Are you saying that part of the view lies outside the windows bounds?

Comment: @indragie I added a screesnhot, see the sadow disappears where the layer-backed view starts. No, it doesn't lie outside of the window, it lies right on the edge. Even if I move it some pixels inside the window, the effect is still there althought not so strong (there's a slight shadow) then.

Comment: @nielsbot Window's content view doesn't have a layer, but if I turn it on nothing changes, I get the same shadowless window border.

Comment: I have to note: my window has setOpaque:NO for specific reasons. If I set it to YES, then everything is ok, but I need it to be NO...

Comment: Try `view.layer.masksToBounds = YES` on the view that's on the edge.

Comment: @indragie I can't test it right now, but I will update you with the result later. Thanks for the tip!